# Legendary and Epic badges - What reputation counts?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-badges

### Rep from upvotes vs All Rep

I have **read quite a few q/a** on here but **I am still confused**.

I checked https://stackoverflow.com/reputation .

For me, it says:

> rep cap was reached **via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days**
>
> earned at least 200 reputation on 5 days

On the legendary badge progress, it shows 5/10 .

[image]

### Rep from Accepts

Finally, in  today's badge progress it doesn't show reputation from accepts.

[image]

[image]

### Questions

1. Am I at 0/200 or 5/200 ?
2. 15 points from accepted answers don't seem to count.. or do they????
3. What about about question upvote reputation?
4. What about bounties?

Thanks

Comment: @Jon Clements So is the badge progress feature buggy? I think it's counting bounties and other such things. I never reached 200 with upvotes only.